# Is manually (and silently) updating a ClickOnce app going to be a stable way of deploying updates?

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I've deployed an application inside a corporate network and I want the update process to require less attention from users, similar to how Google Chrome install updates - in the background. I don't need to give the user a choice to update.

I've used the `System.Deployment` library to detect when new ClickOnce updates are available and install them automatically. I'm wondering if its necessary to restart the app after the update is complete. Currently I invoke `Application.Restart()` at the end of my update script.

But what if (to make the update process more transparent for the user) I performed a 'silent' async update and then displayed an icon prompting the user to restart the app to apply the changes? Would this make the app unstable in any way?

Furthermore, if I ran my custom `InstallUpdate()` process on a timer, say every 30 minutes, would ClickOnce be stable to continue to update for every new version that was released even thought the user has not restarted (nb: I'm expecting the updates to only apply once the user restarts the app)?

Comment: Did you try any of this?

Comment: The only reference I can find to doing it like this is here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163973.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163973.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but did you *try* it? ie. write a program using Click-once, and instead of restarting the application just silently updating it, then update it a couple of times, and then manually restart it. That would easily tell you if this is going to work.

Comment: Not yet, but will test today. I was hoping someone could inform if this would make the app unstable?

Comment: By just trying it and seeing it work, that doesn't at all guarantee there isn't a failure scenario waiting down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few years of doing it like this, we have found that it is possible to silently install updates this way. However there are a few issues to be aware of:

1. If the thread terminates prematurely during the `Update()` (eg: the user exits out of the app while the updating is in progress), the install will become corrupt and the next time the user loads the app, the ClickOnce normal deployment will fire off and re-install the app.
2. The user's desktop icons always redraw (flicker) after an update is installed.
3. Calling `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CheckForUpdate()` more than 65536 times causes a `System.NullReferenceException` [Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d9183f7e-f5c7-46d0-8bb4-411ad923976c/a-privilege-that-the-service-requires-to-function-properly-does-not-exist-in-the-service-account?forum=winformssetup).

   An alternative is not to actually check for an update, I have found that this locks one of my dlls and prevented a form from loading, so use with care:

   ```
   If ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.Update Then ' update app
       console.writeline("update installed")
       ' code to inform user update was sucessfull and they need to restart
   End If
   ```
4. If your ClickOnce project is 32bit, and you run it on an x64 platform, any file associations your app has will break after performing a manual ClickOnce update. See this [MS support case](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800419/clickonce-file-associations-break-for-x86-application-running-on-x64-after-updating) for more details.

Comment: After 2 months of installing updates this way in a production environment with about 10 users, I have only noticed two side-effects: **1)** Windows Desktop will redraw after the update process has finished (noticeable flicker and icons repaint), and **2)** The application will sometimes crash when the user subsequently clicks the "apply and restart" button that calls _Application.Restart()_, however this might not be related to installing updates, I don't know...

Comment: Update: Desktop redraw is probably due to ClickOnce deleting and recreating the desktop shortcut to the app.

Comment: About side effect **2)**, it could happen, in Windows Forms as least, if you open forms after the call to `Application.Restart` (in my case, opening a form in the FormClosing event handler triggered  `InvalidOperationException`) -- it seems instead safe to show message boxes with `MessageBox.Show`. For further information check this [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d7dbae4e-3cf7-45e4-8172-62b18a19207e) in Windows Forms forums (especially the last post).

Comment: @edymtt, yes the crash we where experiencing was probably not related to 'silently' installing updates as I thought, but rather depends on how the application closes down (disposing objects/threads) when you make the call to `Application.Restart()`. Since then I have changed the code to fix this and we don't get this crash any more!

Answer (score 1):

I would think it depends on what your application does at startup, and what it's doing when the update is installed and the application is restarted, and what the update contains. You could try running it and then attaching a debugger to it and see what it's doing and what impact it has.

For example, our application loads a lot of information into memory when it starts up. If the update included a change to one of the data structures, and the app didn't reload the data for some reason, it would cause a problem.

Comment: If you don't restart, I guess that the code currently running hasn't changed so I guess there will be no data structure issue. Except if the application is communicating with other (web services, server, etc.) that may send information in an unexpected format or if you load some data that may have been updated.

Comment: @Julien, yes you need to update the client and server at the same time in these instances, or make sure the changes on the server remain compatible with older versions of the client still running.